# I want an image like the following image. (Question about Plot)

Tags: plotting

I am reading an article about Euler summation formula.

Let $n$ be a positive integer which is greater than or equal to $2$.
Let $f$ be a function from $[1,n]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $g$ be a function from $[1,n]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=f(k)$ if $x\in[k,k+1)$ for some $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.
Let $S:=\{x\in [1,n]\mid f(x)\leq g(x)\}.$
Let $T:=\{x\in [1,n]\mid g(x)< f(x)\}.$
Let $B:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in S, f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)\}.$
Let $R:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in T, g(x)\leq y\leq f(x)\}.$
I want to paint the area $B$ blue.
I want to paint the area $R$ red.

I copied the following code:

```
n = 10;
f[x_] := Sin[x];
rectangles[f_, a_, b_, n_] := {
    Opacity[0.0],
    Blue,
    EdgeForm[Black],
    N@Table[Rectangle[{a + k (b - a)/n, 0}, {a + (k + 1) (b - a)/n, f[a + k (b - a)/n]}], {k, 0, n - 1}]
};
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n}, Epilog -> rectangles[f, 1, n, n-1],
   AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I want an image like the following image:
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: This should be achievable by describing the areas covered by rectangles as a function and using the `Filling` option between the two functions.

Comment: @kirma Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick hack:

```
n = 10;
f[x_] := Sin[x];
rectangles[f_, a_, b_, n_] := {Opacity[0.0], Blue, EdgeForm[Black], 
   N@Table[Rectangle[{a + k (b - a)/n, 0}, {a + (k + 1) (b - a)/n, 
       f[a + k (b - a)/n]}], {k, 0, n - 1}]};
Plot[{f[x], f[Floor[x]]}, {x, 1, n},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Blue, Red}}}, 
 Epilog -> rectangles[f, 1, n, n - 1], AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The stepped function is achieved just by `Floor`, two-sided filling between the normal and stepped function is achieved with `Filling` option and just for completeness, plot style for the stepped function is set to `None`.

Comment: kirma, Thank you very very much for your excellent answer.